# selecting delimiter in regex while selecting portion between lines in case of perl

Tags: regex, perl

The message has detection report:

```
<detection_report>
Test 1
Test 2 
Test 3
</detection_report>

---------------------------------------------
Have a nice day
```

I want to select portion between `<detection_report>` tags, including these two tags.

I have written following code.

```
The message has detection report\:((.|\n|\r)+)(\<\/detection_report\>)
```

but its not working. Can anyone help me with this.

Comment: That is not code, it looks like a regex. You should show the code that uses the regex.

Comment: Also, you should be more specific than "its not working".

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to do the job:

```
perl -ane 'print if /<detection_report>/ .. /<\/detection_report>/' in.txt
```

**output:**

```
<detection_report>
Test 1
Test 2 
Test 3
</detection_report>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a perl one-liner

```
perl -ane 'print $1 // $_ if m{(detection_report.*)} .. m{(.*?</detection_report>)}' file.txt
```

This is close to what `M42` suggested, but it takes into account the possibility that the tags do not exist on their own lines.

Note, if this data is either HTML or XML, then you should use an actual HTML or XML Parser for extracting this data.

Answer (score 0):

There you go:

```
$ cat detection.txt  
The message has detection report:

<detection_report>
Test 1
Test 2 
Test 3
</detection_report>

---------------------------------------------
Have a nice day$ cat regex.pl 
#!/usr/bin/perl

while(<>){ 
    $input.=$_
}

($body) = $input =~ m/(<.*>)/ms;

print $body
$ cat detection.txt  | perl regex.pl 
<detection_report>
Test 1
Test 2 
Test 3
</detection_report>$
```